# Strange behaviour with 2 streams open on the same FileStream

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

I have both a `BinaryReader` and a `BinaryWriter` open on the same underlying `FileStream`. When I seek to a location using the `BinaryWriter` and write a value, it is getting written at the start of the stream instead of the location that was seeked to in the previous line.

My code (simplified):

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
using (var sw = new BinaryWriter(stream))
using (var sr = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    int address;
    int value;

    //Write some data using sw

    //Seek and read a few different places using sr,
    //and set address and value

    sw.BaseStream.Seek(address, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    sw.Write(value);
}
```

The `Position` property is showing the correct value in both the `FileStream` and the `BinaryWriter.BaseStream` when I inspect them immediately after the Seek, yet it is still writing to the start of the stream.

I also noticed that after performing a seek and read with the `BinaryReader`, the data that was initially written to the stream gets shifted forward 4 bytes, filling the first 4 bytes with 0.

What could be causing this strange behaviour? Is using two streams at a time valid?

**UPDATE**

Everything works just fine if I use a `MemoryStream` instead and then write the data from that to my file. So why would this happening with a `FileStream` and not a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Why are you using `sw.BaseStream.Seek` rather than `sw.Seek`?

Comment: Symmetry with having to use `BaseStream.Seek` with `BinaryReader`? Anyways, using `sw.Seek` instead doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I also tried doing all the seeks using the `FileStream` and get the same result.

Comment: Refer to http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/binarywriter-seek-vs-binarywriter-basestream-seek-t1223754.html , The difference between BinaryWriter.Seek() and BinaryWriter.BaseStream.Seek() is that the latter flush the data before repositioning. To be precise the flushing is performed everytime you use the BaseStream property. May be what you need is flushing?

Comment: @V-SHY Please see my update. Also the same problem occurs with either method.

Comment: That is what I want to happen, hence why I am using `FileMode.Create`